# Change name and move file in C#

Tags: c#, .net, openfiledialog, system.io.file

```
private void btn_add_image_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.Title = "Choose a file";
        openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "  JPEG Files (*.jpg;*.jpeg;*.jpe;*.jfif)|*.jpg|All Files (*.*)|*.*";
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
        string file_name = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        string filename2 = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(file_name);
    }


    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
            pictureBox1.Image = null;
            string[] extension = getExtension("images\\" + userid);
            if (File.Exists("images\\" + userid + extension[0]))
            {   
                File.Delete("resimler\\" + userid + extension[0]);
            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("İmage cannot find");
        }
```

I want to Change File name and save , so i wrote this code if file exists , than delete file and save the choosen with userid name but i cant do change name and save file

Comment: "I cannot" is not a very useful description of your problem. *Why*? Do you need to read a book on file handling in C#? Did you try a specific method and it did not work? Why did it not work? Did you get errors? Compile time or runtime errors? Please provide enough information so people *can* help you with your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (File.Exists(@"\path\to\source"))
{
    File.Move(@"\path\to\source",@"\path\to\destination")
}
```

Comment: All those \ need to be \\ or you have to use @

Answer (score 1):

I think both your problems can me handled with this bit of code.

```
System.IO.File.Move("old_file_name_path", "new_file_name_path");
```

This moves the file to a new filename. Take a look here: [File.Move](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move.aspx)

But, I really don't get what you are asking here:

> i wrote this code if file exists , than delete file and save the
>   choosen with userid name but i cant do change name and save file

Can you be more specific?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All

```
private void btn_save_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();
        pictureBox1.Image = null;
        string source = openFileDialog1.FileName;
        string[] extension = getExtension(source);
        string destination = "images\\" + userid + extension[0];
        System.IO.File.Move(source, destination);
        pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile("images\\" + userid + extension[0]);

    }
```